# Cygwin on Windows: Can't open display

Tags: windows, cygwin, display

I am running Windows 10 on my Surface Pro 3. I installed Cygwin and also added some useful packages (gvim, nedit, emacs, vim, g++). However, when I run gvim, I get "Can't open display". The same thing happens with nedit. When I did echo $DISPLAY, I showed nothing so I set the DISPLAY to :0.0. I still get "can't open display." I tried removing cygwin and re-installing but I get the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like the X11 server isn't running. Have you worked through the steps at http://x.cygwin.com ?

Comment: Let me also clarify that I am running Cygwin on my machine, where I am an admin. Yes, I did install the x11 packages, and looked through the x11 issues but that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 30):

Unix GUI programs display through an [X server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture). Cygwin doesn't automatically start an X server. You need to [install](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html#setup-cygwin-x-installing) the packages `xorg-server` and `xinit`, and [run `startxwin`](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html#using-starting).

Comment: As of 2017/01, startxwin is included in the xinit package

Answer (score 12):

Source : [CygwinX FAQ](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html) :

Since X server 1.17, by default the server does not listen for TCP/IP connections, only accepting local connections on a unix domain socket.
For local clients, use `DISPLAY=:0.0`, rather than `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`, `DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0`, `DISPLAY=::1:0.0`, etc

If it does not work (if you are connecting from remote): Use the `-listen tcp` option to restore the previous behaviour, allowing the X server to open a TCP/IP socket as well e.g.

```
startxwin -- -listen tcp
```

Finally, don't forget to run `xhost +` in the Cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 5):

What helped me is changing

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 <mycommand>
```

to

```
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 <mycommand>
```

Comment: odd, running locally, after installing all the packages and first running xlaunch with the default display (0), the following command works for me: DISPLAY=:0.0 gimp

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [XLaunch/Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

- Open XLaunch, choose "Multiple Windows", and set a Display number (doesn't matter).
- In Cygwin, `export DISPLAY=[whatever your XLaunch Display number is]`.
- Launch your program with `gvim &`

Answer (score 1):

How I got it working:

- Install packages `xorg-server` and `xinit`.
- Run this commands in a Cygwin shell window:

  `startxwin`

  `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 xterm`

However, to be honest, the default CygWin console is nicer than XTerm, so I continued to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I run graphic programs without a script, i.e. `startxwin <myapp>` the following way:

1. For my command in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```bsh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

2. Start the XWin Server with the standard command:

```psh
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; exec /usr/bin/startxwin"
```

3. Start your graph application from terminal, for example:

```
/bin/kate
```

P.S. I solved my error with Eclipse IDE:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display <...>
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I added a Windows system variable: `DISPLAY=:0.0`

Answer (score -1):

just export it

export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

to make persistant add that to your .bash_profile